# Zipping Two File with Same Content and Encoding them to base64 giving different response

Tags: c#, .net, zip, gzip

I need to encode the zip file in base64 formats.

I followed the following approach

```
  string text = File.ReadAllText("../../../SampleDat.dat");
            byte[] compress0 = Compress(stringbyte);
            string short_com0 = base64_encode(compress0);

   public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
        {
            using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                zipStream.Close();
                return compressedStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public string base64_encode(byte[] data)
        {
            if (data == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        }
```

After using this I got this encoded string.

```
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
```

When I created zip manually and read file in the code and compress that file

```
 //file zipped manually
  string filePath1 = "../../../git_only/oraclehcm1/dbscripts/SampleDat.zip";
  byte[] physicalfile1 = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath1);
  string long_com1 = base64_encode(physicalfile1);
```

The response I get is

```
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
```

This is the actual response . I also noticed the two zip are of the different size and the zip I which I created programmatically , The files in this zip have no extensions.

Please help me to create the second encoding through program and > .NET version I am using is 4.5
and I cannot use Zip.createDirectory() method due to project dependencies.

Any help is appreaciated .
Thanks in Advnance!

Comment: You have an extra ASCII decoding step in there when reading SampleDat.dat - have you tried using File.ReadAllBytes directly instead?   Also, when you created "SampleDat.zip" manually, what did you use?  If it's a variant of PKZip (e.g. 7Zip), that could be your problem: Gzip and PKZip are different compression formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is a gzip file, the second one is a zip file. If you want to make a zip file, try the `ZipFile` class as opposed to the `GZipStream` class.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect two different Zip algorithms/libraries to yield the same output.  For one, in the programmatic way, the file metadata (name, modification date, attributes) are not set, while the command line version will include all that information for unzipping purposes.

Plus libraries update at different cadence than standalones, and you might not have the fixes synchronized to reliably match the outputs.